# How can I check if DataMapper is connected?

Tags: ruby, datamapper

Active Record has a method called `connected?` that returns true if Active Record is connected. Is there an equivalent for DataMapper? I can't find anything in the API docs. And if not, what is the most proper solution to check this?

Comment: This information is adapter specific. Can you tell us about the adapter you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataMapper is multi-adapter ORM and expects each adapter to maintain connection to it's database. Some adapters even have no connection, like yaml or in-memory. So, generally, you can't know if DataMapper connected or not.